# How do you have different views to serve different content types in pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

The documentation seems to indicate you can use the 'accept' view_config param for this, like this:

```
@view_config(
    route_name='data',
    request_method='POST',
    accept='application/json',
    renderer='json',
)
def json_post_view(self):
  ...

@view_config(
    route_name='data',
    request_method='POST',
    renderer='blah:templates/data.mako',
)
def form_post_view(self):
  ...
```

However, practically speaking using wget to post to the url, like this:

```
wget -q -O - --post-file=data.json http://localhost:6543/data
```

or:

```
wget -q -O - --post-file=data.json --header="Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:6543/data
```

or using a browser to post to the url...

*all* result in the same thing; the json_post_view() view is invoked.

What am I doing wrong here? The accept parameter doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use a predicate to dispatch to different views, as you've done. However `accept` is for the `Accept` header which is for forming your response. The incoming data is in the `Content-Type` header for which pyramid does not come with a default predicate. You can easily write your own, however.

```
class ContentTypePredicate(object):
    def __init__(self, val, config):
        self.val = val

    def text(self):
        return 'content type = %s' % self.val
    phash = text

    def __call__(self, context, request):
        return request.content_type == self.val

config.add_view_predicate('content_type', ContentTypePredicate)

@view_config(content_type='application/json')
# ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Content-type` header designate the type of the body of the request. For the type you want the server to return, you should use the `Accept` header.

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests